# Does someone in world already have antibodies against Wuhan coronavirus?

Tags: virus

There's this [interactive map](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html?fbclid=IwAR3aU7u4xpWmqSI7elfv7edaAI3ozjS5haG6wm2eChMKPOGJaAEw4luKki8#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6) showing progression of Wuhan coronavirus. And among other indicators it also shows number of cured individuals (38 at the moment), which is less than number of deaths, but still. Doesn't it mean that those individuals now have antibodies against the given virus?

**UPDATE:**

I mean if there's someone with antibodies, and they had a video on the national TV, releasing cured patient. Why they can't use the case to accelerate vaccine development?

Comment: It almost certainly does but I very much doubt there's data available with which to answer the question.

Comment: Antibodies are not used in vaccines. Vaccines involve getting a patient's own immune system to recognize an antigen prior to (or near to) exposure to the actual pathogen. As such, they typically involve parts of the pathogen itself.